# Submit Button With Error Message and then redirect location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to have an error message for the button and then redirect to the url. I'm not sure on how to do that. I wanted to put it into JQuery. I'm new to JQuery. It's like the user have to upload a file then click on Submit. "The submit button will redirect user to the url from the QRCode which will be displayed on the text.

Submit Button:

```
   <div id="form1">
   <input type=text placeholder="Tracking Code" class=qrcode-text id="url">
   <label class=qrcodeBtn>
       <input type=file accept="image/*" capture="environment"  onchange="openCamera(this);">
</label>
<input type=button value="Submit" onclick = "windowLocate()" class="btnQRCode" id="submitButton">
```

Javascript for Redirect:

```
      function windowLocate() {
        var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
        document.write("Redirecting to the url in few seconds...");
        setTimeout(function () { window.location = url; }, 3000);
      }
```

Comment: You can try the window.open() function. It's just a pure javascript.

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: Can you show me what element were you using in your url?

Comment: <input type=text placeholder="Tracking Code" class=qrcode-text id="url">

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd do it:

```
function windowLocate() {
    if (document.querySelector("input[type='file']").value) {
        var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
        document.write("Redirecting to the url in few seconds...");
        setTimeout(function () { 
            window.open(url); 
        }, 3000);
    }
    else {
        alert("Error message");
    }
}
```

Comment: but i want to add an error message like Please upload a file before submitting it and then redirect to the url

Comment: When  I click on the submit button, it doesn't give me an error message saying "Please upload a file"

Comment: @Rod My code will alert "Error message" if there is nothing in the file upload. Do you want a success message?

Comment: When I click on the submit button, it doesn't give me an error message saying "Please upload a file" but it redirect the page without the url

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to check if users already uploaded the file or not.

Add id to the input tag.

```
<label class=qrcodeBtn>
   <input type=file accept="image/*" capture="environment" id="uploadImage" onchange="openCamera(this);">
</label>
```

Then change the windowLocate code with this.

```
function windowLocate() {
    if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length != 0) {
        var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
        document.write("Redirecting to the url in few seconds...");
        setTimeout(function () { 
            window.open(url);
        }, 3000);
    }
    else {
        alert("Please upload the file first."); //you can change the error message
    }
}
```

Comment: When the URL from the QR code image is decoded into the text file once the QR Code image is uploaded, it can't redirect the page based on the url. It keeps on saying "Please upload the file first".

Comment: i'm sorry i think i have misunderstand what do you mean on your question before, may i know whats inside the function openCamera(this) ?